# Angular 2/5 declare directives in lazy modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I wants to reuse a directive in multiple modules. I can´t declare the directive in parentmodule because all childmodules are loaded by lazy loading.
If i declare the same directive in both childmodules i get an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type AddDirective is part
>   of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModule and GdprModule! Please
>   consider moving AddDirective to a higher module that imports
>   SharedModule and GdprModule. You can also create a new NgModule that
>   exports and includes AddDirective then import that NgModule in
>   SharedModule and GdprModule.

AddDirective is a simple directive which provide me ViewContainerRef which i need for dynamical components. I add them by following tutorial:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Do i have to create a own directive for every lazy module or is there any way to provide the same directive by shared module for example?

SharedModule:

```js
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      declarations: [
         AddDirective
      ]
    })
```

LazyModule:

```js
    import { SharedModule } from './pathToShared/sharaed.module';

    @NgModule({
     imports: [ SharedModule ],
     declarations: [ LazyComponent],
     entryComponents: [ DynamicalComponent ]
    })
    export class LazyModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create shared module. Add the modules that are used multiple times and export them.
for example

`shared.module.ts`

```js
    import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { AlertModule, TimepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

    import { SweetAlertService } from './../sweetalert2.service';

    import { UnmaskDirective } from '../../directive/unmask.directive';
    import { FileUploadComponent } from '../file-upload/file-upload.component';

    @NgModule({
       imports: [
       CommonModule, NgbModule.forRoot(), AlertModule.forRoot(),TimepickerModule.forRoot(), FileUploadModule
      ],
      declarations: [UnmaskDirective, FileUploadComponent],
      providers: [SweetAlertService],
      exports: [
        NgbModule, AlertModule, TimepickerModule, UnmaskDirective, FileUploadComponent, FileUploadModule
      ]
    })
    export class SharedModule {
      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: SharedModule,
          providers: [SweetAlertService]
        }
      }
    }
```

now import shared module in whenever required for example `register.module.ts`

```js
    import { SharedModule } from './../../common/sharaed/sharaed.module';

    @NgModule({
     imports: [ SharedModule ],
     declarations: [ UserComponent],
     entryComponents: []
    })
    export class RegisterModule { }
```

now register module has all the modules that are included in shared module

you can also refer this links [shared.module.ts](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-first-look-examples/blob/master/_examples/storyline-tracker/app/shared/shared.module.ts),  [angular real world example shared module](https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts), [angular-modules-feature-modules](https://johnpapa.net/introducing-angular-modules-feature-modules-2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to rebuild your code but it doesn´t works. I added my modules to my question. I also don´t understand your whole code. For example for what is you static forRoot responsible?

Comment: @NgModule({
   imports: [
   CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [AddDirective],
  providers: [],
  exports: [AddDirective ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: []
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared module and add the directive it in and import shared module in app.module.ts

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried to do that but it doesnt works. What did i wrong? I added some content to my question.